# The Jehovah’s Witnesses state that Jesus was God's first creation? How do they reconcile that with Genesis 1:26, Genesis 2:15-18?

Tags: genesis, christology, jehovahs-witnesses, creation

They state in this [Watchtower](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2005681#h=6)

> Since all created things had a beginning, there was a time when God was alone. Countless ages ago, however, God became a Creator. Who was his first creation? The last book of the Bible identifies Jesus as “the beginning of the creation by God.” (Revelation 3:14) Jesus is “the firstborn of all creation.” That is so “because by means of him all other things were created in the heavens and upon the earth, the things visible and the things."

Since according to them, "there was a time when God was alone" why don't we see any evidence at Genesis 1 or 2 that Jesus was created before Adam and Eve? Why do they jump to Revelation 3:14, the last book of the Bible? Moreover, even if you jump to Proverbs 8:22 it's still well after Genesis 1,2 when man was created after the heavens and earth were created. (Genesis 1:1.)

Since they say "God was all alone" how do they justify the following that Jesus was with God here: :“The Word” was with Jehovah God “in the beginning,” when “the heavens and the earth” were created. He was the one to whom God said: “Let us make man in our image.” (John 1:1; Genesis 1:1, 26) Jehovah’s firstborn Son was there at his Father’s side, actively working with him. At Proverbs 8:22-31, he is represented as saying: “I came to be beside [the Creator] as a master worker, and I came to be the one he was specially fond of day by day, I being glad before him all the time.”

There is no mention of Jesus/Him being with God before the beginning as God's first creation before Genesis chapter one and two? Finally, and this is this is the real question I am asking. How could God who was all alone create anything "WITHOUT" Jesus Christ at John 1:3? "All things came into being by Him, and "WITHOUT" Him nothing came into being that has come into being." The JW quotes are from the [Watchtower](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2005681#h=6)

Comment: The angels applauded the founding of the earth so they were created before “in the beginning”      JWs do not teach that the creation of the universe was the first creation by God.  Jesus was directly created by Jehovah eons before. Angels were created by Jehovah with Jesus serving as the instrument through which they were created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If according to the Jehovah Witnesses that "there was a time when God was alone," who was with God at John 1:1?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75309/if-according-to-the-jehovah-witnesses-that-there-was-a-time-when-god-was-alone)

Comment: @Kris There's the beginning of a fine answer.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast  thanks but this is already answered in a previous 007 question

Answer (score 4):

The idea that “Jesus was God’s first creation” is based on:

Colossians 1:13-16 (ESV)

> He has delivered us from the domain of darkness and transferred us to
> the kingdom of his beloved Son, 14 in whom we have redemption, the
> forgiveness of sins. 13 He is the image of the invisible God, the
> firstborn of all creation. 16 For by- him all things were created, in
> heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or
> dominions or rulers or authorities—all things were created through him
> and for him.

This scripture identifies the Son (Jesus) of the Father (Jehovah) as “the firstborn of all creation”, and states that “by him all things were created, in heaven and on earth”.

Genesis 1:26 (NIV)

> Then God said, "Let us make mankind in our image, in our likeness, so
> that they may rule over the fish in the sea and the birds in the sky,
> over the livestock and all the wild animals, and over all the
> creatures that move along the ground."

Note that in Genesis 1:26 it is written let “us” make mankind in “our image”. This thus confirms that God was not alone, and was thus at least with Jesus, since all other beings were created by Jesus as was stated in Colossians 1. No contradictions here.

This is also supported by John 17 3-5:

> John 17 3 Now this is eternal life: that they know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom you have sent. 4 I have brought you glory on earth by finishing the work you gave me to do. 5 And now, Father, glorify me in your presence with **the glory I had with you before the world began.** (NIV)

Genesis 2:15 (Darby Bible Translation)

> And Jehovah Elohim took Man, and put him into the garden of Eden, to
> till it and to guard it.

So after creating Man (together), God did some things described in Genesis 2:15-18.

No contradictions here.

Maybe you question the necessity that God existed for a period of time without Jesus.

The being of the Son (Jesus) is associated with a beginning (Colossians 1, John 1, Proverbs 8). Whereas the Father (Jehovah) is associated with eternity in both the past and future direction (Psalms 90:2).

In the last part of your question you mention: “How could Got who was all alone create anything without Jesus? In the view that this would be a contradiction, Colossians 1:13 would already contradict itself. This would be a way of reasoning more like maximizing the number of contradictions, which is of course allowed, but not one Jehovah witnesses are pursuing. The guiding principle and objective for Jehovah Witnesses to formulate biblical teachings is, basically to find a view which minimizes contradictions among all canonical bible scriptures. But of course this is not always easy, and might be subject to discussion, and change of insight.

In the JW view everything (except God and Jesus himself) was created by or through or with the help of Jesus. Since Jesus had a start, this thus  also implies that the universe had a start. Before the start of the physical universe, there would also not be any concept of time as we know it. And discussions about it would be Metaphysical speculation, and since the bible also does not tell much about that time, it would also be religious speculation.

Using a mathematical analogy of lines, we see Jehovah as an line without beginning and without end, and we see Jesus as a line with a beginning and without end.

Answer (score 2):

The JW publication *“Insight on the Scriptures” Vol. I* has a section headed “Creation” from pp 526 with four and a half pages of text. Looking through it, I noted only one occurrence of Genesis 1:26 on p 527, but no mention or even a reference to Genesis 2:15-18. This is what is stated about Genesis 1:26 -

> “In view of the close association of Jehovah and his only-begotten Son
>   in creative activity and because that Son is “the image of the
>   invisible God” (Col 1:15; 2Co 4:4), it was evidently to his
>   only-begotten Son and master worker that Jehovah spoke in saying, “Let
>   us make man in our image.” -Ge 1:26. After creating his only-begotten
>   Son, Jehovah used him in bringing the heavenly angels into existence.
>   This preceded the founding of the earth, as Jehovah revealed when
>   questioning Job … (Job 38:4-7)  It was after the creation of these
>   heavenly spirit creatures that the material heavens and earth and all
>   elements were made, or brought into existence. And, since Jehovah is
>   the one primarily responsible for all this creative work, it is
>   ascribed to him – Ne 9:6; Ps 136:1, 5-9. The Scriptures, in stating,
>   “In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth”  (Ge 1:1)
>   leave matters indefinite as to time.”

I note that the Jehovah’s Witnesses do not include the Holy Spirit in Genesis 1:26 but only believe that Jehovah was addressing the Son, and none other. I also note their sentence, “And, since Jehovah is the one primarily responsible for all this creative work, it is ascribed to him” as the likely explanation they might give for Genesis 2:15-18 where God (not the Son) is said to make Eve. Also, their claim that the phrase ‘in the beginning’  “leaves matters indefinite as to time” could be employed by them to deal with John 1:1, which you also ask about.

However, it remains for Jehovah’s Witnesses to offer any explanation as to why the Holy Spirit-inspired Genesis account makes no mention of the Son actually being the first created ‘thing’ Jehovah made and/or that this Son was utterly involved in all creation (apart from himself which, as you enquire about, does not appear to harmonize with John 1:3). The Holy Spirit, after all, IS credited with a crucial role in Genesis 1: 2. Hopefully, some Jehovah’s Witnesses will respond to outstanding issues, as what I have quoted from one of their books is by no means exhaustive. There will be other quotations that could be proffered, no doubt.  I hope this partial answer encourages them to respond further.